# Need to replace fixed value with string or text box value

Tags: c#, json

How can I replace the value \"username\" with the value of a text box or a string?

```
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json",
    "{\"myname\":\"username\",\n\"mypass\":\"password\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried and explain what you are not managing with it

Comment: I want to replace the fixed values of the json format with the ones typed on a textbox... this way I can control the data sent to the API from a Windows Form.

Comment: Please refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). When posting a question you should show what you have tried. We can help correct your code.. But with no relevant attempt how can we correct it?

Comment: For example - it seems like you are constructing the json hard coded (except the specific change you want) - so have you looked into formatting a string or `string.Replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a String.Format() will always be better.

```
var jsonStr = String.Format("{{\"myname\":\"{0}\",\n\"mypass\":\"{1}\"}}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
```

My Bad. We are formatting a json string, so our curly braces '{' and '}' should be escaped as '{{' and  '}}'

Comment: better option :) also you can use string interpolation :)

Comment: I dont see any errors but when I run it it says:         
System.FormatException occurred
Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
:-(

Comment: Awesome, that was it... Now I am getting a different Error code when sending the data on this format to the API - Any idea what this error mean (UnsupportedMediaType) - I am comparing the json format of the data when is sent with fixed values and is the same but for some reason using String.Format is no likey... Thank you!

Comment: are you sure your API does accepts the application/json media type? because I don't think string.format has to do anything with that

Comment: Yup, I am testing with Postman... I figured it that I was missing the "application/json" on my request.AddParameter              ->                 equest.AddParameter("application/json", jsonStr, ParameterType.RequestBody);

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `String.Replace()` method.
Find the code below.

```
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json",
    "{\"myname\":\"username\",\n\"mypass\":\"password\"}".Replace("\"username\"", txtBox1.Text), ParameterType.RequestBody);
```